# An Error on Apache Ignite Web Console

Tags: java, ignite, web-console

I am a beginner in ignite and I am learning to use Web Console.After I generated the pojo classes and I wanted to download the whole JAVA project. But the Web Console shows that

```
Failed to generate project files. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

And I checked out the source javascript file, and it prints:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at parse (blob:http://localhost:9000/3d17a19b-8883-40b4-a320-e88c4917f5f4:25264)
    at IgniteVersion.since (blob:http://localhost:9000/3d17a19b-8883-40b4-a320-e88c4917f5f4:25368)
    at Function.clusterGeneral (blob:http://localhost:9000/3d17a19b-8883-40b4-a320-e88c4917f5f4:23255)
    at Function.igniteConfiguration (blob:http://localhost:9000/3d17a19b-8883-40b4-a320-e88c4917f5f4:23155)
    at onmessage (blob:http://localhost:9000/3d17a19b-8883-40b4-a320-e88c4917f5f4:34012)
```

And I continued to locate the exact points, it came down to this:

```
var parse = function parse(ver) {
    // Development or built from source ZIP.
    ver = ver.replace(/(-DEV|-n\/a)$/i, ''); //here is the problem
```

How can I fix this problem and download the JAVA project? The JAVA project is very important to me.

Thanks for you advice in advanced!

Comment: What version of Web Console did you used?

Comment: I have this problem too. 
I use version 2.1

Comment: I use version 2.1